# Where does the WTP Eclipse plugin write it's error log?

Tags: eclipse-wtp

Where does the WTP Eclipse plugin write it's error log?  I'm not talking about Tomcat's log, but rather the log for the plugin in Eclipse.

Comment: When I check out the "Error Log" view, I see errors from my WLS server instance logged.  I did a little more digging and found in my workspace under the .metadata folder a ".log" file.  This appears to be the same file that is showing up under "Error Log".  Is this maybe the one you're looking for?

Comment: Perhaps, can you provide a relative file path for an example?  I'm looking for where the stack dump is for when I see a popup error message, such as "Tomcat failed to start", the details button only shows me the class name of the Exception being thrown.

Comment: relative path would be <your_workspace_dir>\.metadata\.log

Comment: submit that as an answer please ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I check out the "Error Log" view, I see errors from my WLS server instance logged. I did a little more digging and found in my workspace under the .metadata folder a ".log" file. This appears to be the same file that is showing up under "Error Log".

Relative path to the log would be `<your_workspace_dir>\.metadata\.log`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, exceptions are just logged to the .log file @ ${workspace}/.metadata/.log